# Sitecore Headless : How to configure editing host in Azure Paas?

Tags: jss

We are planning to have Sitecore Headless solution. The Sitecore CMS will be hosted in Azure Paas (Sitecore Managed Cloud). The frontend application (rendering host) will be hosted in vercel. The frontend application will access items, media and layout information through experience edge.
Now for experience editor we need to set up a editing host so that the experience editor can access the frontend code(Nextjs).  I researched some of sitecore documents to get information to set up editing host like [this](https://doc.sitecore.com/xmc/en/developers/xm-cloud/walkthrough--configuring-external-editing-hosts-for-xm-cloud-instances.html) but they all are for XM Cloud.

In local set up Experience Editor works through http://localhost:3000/api/editing/render endpoint.
So how does it work in case of production environment ? I could not find any documents to set up editing host for Azure Pass. Please let me know any information on the setup or point me to any document which describes the set up.

Comment: Check this one: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/hd/210/sitecore-headless-development/walkthrough--connecting-a-next-js-jss-app-to-sitecore-editors.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Sitecore CMS is hosted on Azure, so you have a public URL for Sitecore CMS eg. `https://<YourAzureHostName>.azurewebsites.net`

Your front end is hosted on Vercel, So you have a public URL eg. `https://<YourVercelDomainName>.vercel.app`

- In the root of the Next.js JSS application directory, Go to `/sitecore/config` folder and open `<app-name>.config` file and make sure the below patch is enabled with the correct value.

```
<sites>
      <!--
        JSS Site Registration
        This configures the site with Sitecore - i.e. host headers, item paths.
        If your JSS app lives within an existing Sitecore site, this may not be necessary.

        IMPORTANT: JSS sites ship in 'live mode', which makes development and testing easy,
        but disables workflow and publishing. Before going to production, change the `database`
        below to `web` instead of `master`.-->
      
      <site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            inherits="website"
            name="app-name"
            hostName="YourAzureHostName.azurewebsites.net"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/app-name"
            startItem="/home"
            database="master" /> 
    </sites>
```

- On the configuration`/sitecore/javaScriptServices/apps` path, make sure `serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl` and `serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl` are pointed to the correct values.

```
<apps>
        <!--
          JSS App Registration
          The JSS app needs to be registered in order to support layout service and import services.

          There are many available attributes, and they inherit the defaults if not explicitly specified here.
          Defaults are defined in `/App_Config/Sitecore/JavaScriptServices/Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.Apps.config`

          NOTE: graphQLEndpoint enables _Integrated GraphQL_. If not using integrated GraphQL, it can be removed.

          NOTE: layoutServiceConfiguration should be set to "default" when using GraphQL Edge schema.
          When using integrated GraphQL with Edge schema, a $language value is injected
          since language is required in all Edge queries. "jss" configuration does not do this (which is backwards
          compatible with JSS versions < 18.0.0).
        -->
        <app name="app-name"
            layoutServiceConfiguration="default"
            sitecorePath="/sitecore/content/<tenant-name>/Home"
            useLanguageSpecificLayout="true"
            graphQLEndpoint="/sitecore/api/graph/edge"
            inherits="defaults"
            serverSideRenderingEngine="http"
            serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl="https://<YourVercelDomainName>.vercel.app/api/editing/render"
            serverSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl="https://<YourVercelDomainName>.vercel.app"
        />
      </apps>
```

- Make sure to update JSS EDITING SECRET in this config.

```
<!--
        JSS EDITING SECRET
        To secure the Sitecore editor endpoint exposed by your Next.js app (see `serverSideRenderingEngineEndpointUrl` below),
        a secret token is used. This is taken from an env variable by default, but could be patched and set directly by uncommenting.
        This (server-side) value must match your client-side value, which is configured by the JSS_EDITING_SECRET env variable (see the Next.js .env file).
        We recommend an alphanumeric value of at least 16 characters. />
      -->
        <setting name="JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Http.JssEditingSecret" value="Random_JSS_Editing_Secret_Key" />
```

- Open `scjssconfig.json` file, and update `layoutServiceHost` and `deployUrl`,

```
{
  "sitecore": {
    "instancePath": "",
    "layoutServiceHost": "https://<YourAzureHostName>.azurewebsites.net",
    "deployUrl": "https://<YourAzureHostName>.azurewebsites.net/sitecore/api/jss/import",
    "apiKey": "{Sitecore_API_KEY}",
    "deploySecret": "Random_Generated_Deploy_Secret"
  }
}
```

- Open .env file and make sure you have following variables defined:

```
PUBLIC_URL=https://<YourVercelDomainName>.vercel.app
JSS_EDITING_SECRET=Random_JSS_Editing_Secret_Key
SITECORE_API_KEY={Sitecore_API_KEY}
SITECORE_API_HOST=https://<YourAzureHostName>.azurewebsites.net
JSS_APP_NAME=app-name
```

- Build (`npm run build`) and deploy the app to Vercel (`vercel --prod`)
- Make sure `app-name.config` is deployed to Sitecore root.
- Open Sitecore CMS and go to  `/sitecore/content/<TenantName>/Home/Settings` and update `Server side rendering engine endpoint URL` and `ServerSideRenderingEngineApplicationUrl`

[image]